# What does 'set -- $REPLY' do?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

```
#!/bin/bash 
command1 |while read
do
set -- $REPLY
command2
done
```

I was browsing the net and I came across this  piece of code.
What does 'set -- $REPLY' do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It splits down $REPLY into tokens and put them into $@ (arguments)

`$REPLY` is the implicit target for `while read` expression. But do remember that using `while read` with implicit target is a bash-ism and it's supported in e.g. `ash` (but supported in `zsh`). Better use `while read REPLY`

Comment: then what does $REPLY do?